# Can spark ignore unreadable files?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a file structure in the following form

`s3://<bucket>/year=2018/month=11/day=26/hour=10/department=x/part-xxxxx.gz.parquet`

My AWS Credentials do NOT have access to all the `department=` values, only a few.

I'm trying to perform

```
df = spark.read.parquet("s3://<bucket>/year=2018/")
```

And that fails with

```
java.io.IOException: Could not read footer: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file FileStatus{path=s3://<bucket>/year=2018/month=11/day=26/hour=10/department=yyyyyy/part-xxxxx.gz.parquet; isDirectory=false; length=104448; replication=0; blocksize=0; modification_time=0; access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false}
```

It fails obviously because I can only access `department=x` and not `department=yyyy`, my question is : *is there a way to just silently ignore those?*

My current workaround is to construct **only valid paths** like this:

```
   tmpl = 's3://<bucket>/year=2018/month=11/day=26/hour={hour}/department=x/'
   df = spark.read.parquet(*list(tmpl.format(hour=hour) for hour in range(1,24)))
```

which is very **cumbersome** because

1. some paths may not exists (missing data for some hours, etc).
2. `spark.read.parquet` does not take a list or a generator as input, so I'm forced to use the splat/unpack operator to convert everything to individual arguments. Not sure if that works ok with thousands of paths.

Is there a better way to load this data without a changing the file structure (which I do not control)?

Answer (score 0):

> It fails obviously because I can only access department=x and not
>   department=yyyy, my question is : is there a way to just silently
>   ignore those?

as per file status object you have read write access ( `permission=rw-rw-rw-`) to the file you mentioned in the log. It might be other issue with file path.

> java.io.IOException: Could not read footer: java.io.IOException: Could
>   not read footer for file
>   FileStatus{path=s3:///year=2018/month=11/day=26/hour=10/department=yyyyyy/part-xxxxx.gz.parquet; isDirectory=false; length=104448; replication=0; blocksize=0;
>   modification_time=0; access_time=0; owner=; group=;
>   permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false}

From the above error you are passing fileStatus object in string format which is not correct.

you have to pass `fileStat.getPath.toString` i.e. in your case `path=s3:///year=2018/month=11/day=26/hour=10/department=yyyyyy/part-xxxxx.gz.parquet;`

df = spark.read.parquet(...) will work.

if you want to pass folder of parquet files you can pass.

or you want filter certain files below example code scala snippet you can use

```
/**
    * getAllFilePath.
    *
    * @param filePath Path
    * @param fs       FileSystem
    * @return list of absolute file path present in given path
    * @throws FileNotFoundException
    * @throws IOException
    */
  @throws[FileNotFoundException]
  @throws[IOException]
  def getAllFilePath(filePath: Path, fs: FileSystem): ListBuffer[String] = {
    val fileList = new ListBuffer[String]
    val fileStatus = fs.listStatus(filePath)
    for (fileStat <- fileStatus) {
      logInfo(s"file path Name : ${fileStat.getPath.toString} length is  ${fileStat.getLen}")
      if (fileStat.isDirectory) fileList ++= (getAllFilePath(fileStat.getPath, fs))
      else if (fileStat.getLen > 0 && !fileStat.getPath.toString.isEmpty) {
        logInfo("fileStat.getPath.toString" + fileStat.getPath.toString)
        fileList.foreach(println)
        fileList += fileStat.getPath.toString
      } else if (fileStat.getLen == 0) {
        logInfo(" length zero files \n " + fileStat)

        // fs.rename(fileStat.getPath, new Path(fileStat.getPath+"1"))
      }
    }
    fileList
  }
```

like this example

```
    val fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(inputPath), spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
 yourFiles = getAllFilePath(new Path(inputPath), fs)

val df = spark.read.parquet(yourFiles:_*)
```

Comment: Solved issue or your problem is something different?